# How to preserve MS-Office add-in state beyond taskpane lifecycle?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm evaluating the new [MS-Office add-in Javascript platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/) to see if can use it to manage connections to a non-standard data source in Excel worksheets.

I've followed the [Excel quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery) to produce a taskpane icon on the Data tab that successfully exercises my Javascript code to connect to the data source via web-socket and populate a table in the worksheet with updates on that data.

I would like to be able to close the taskpane without deleting my data connection and callbacks. Ideally, I could have separate buttons on the ribbon for each major operation (connect, disconnect, request data stream, etc.). I would like each of these buttons to modify the state of the underlying connector that would exist for the lifetime of the worksheet, rather than only for the life of the taskpane.

Can anybody make recommendations as to the best approach for this lifecycle?

Comment: I think you can use the shared runtime solution. set the runtime lifetime 
 = long to take advantage of this feature. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime

Comment: Thanks, yes that did help. I found an excellent example of this here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/master/Samples/excel-shared-runtime-global-state.
It's not *quite* what I was hoping -- now I have one static runtime for all of Excel. I don't suppose there's a way to create a runtime per worksheet??